# How can I get selected data from a combobox on a website into Excel with Selenium VBA?

Tags: vba, selenium

I want data from the website. The number comes up, the name does not.
I want the name.

```vb
Sayfa1.Cells(row, 19).Value = bot.FindElementByName("BeyanAdresi.IlKodu").Value

"select class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field İl must be a number." data-val-required="İl Alanı Gereklidir" id="BeyanAdresi_IlKodu" name="BeyanAdresi.IlKodu"><option value="">Lütfen Seçiniz</option
option value="1">ADANA/option>option value="2">ADIYAMAN/option>option value="3">AFYONKARAHİSAR/option>option value="4">AĞRI/option>option value="68">AKSARAY/option>option value="5">option>..."
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put .text instead of .value. Just like:

Sayfa1.Cells(row, 19)= bot.FindElementByName("BeyanAdresi.IlKodu").**Text**

Comment: i tried but then it takes all the data in the combobox LİKE ADANA ADIYAMAN AFYONKARAHİSAR ....

Comment: Can u send the link? It seens to have 5 values. Maybe if you click with the right botton and cupy the xpath you can get an especific value.

Something like this:
bot.findelementbyxpath("//*[@id='ide']/div[2]/table[4]/tbody/tr[10]/td[3]")

Comment: I cannot write because it is a link with a special password. Cities belonging to Turkey and the codes of these cities are available. When you select the city in the combobox, the city in the page source becomes "selected". Can't we write some code from the "Selected"?

Comment: select class="form-control valid" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field İl must be a number." data-val-required="İl Alanı Gereklidir" id="BeyanAdresi_IlKodu" name="BeyanAdresi.IlKodu"  option value="" Lütfen Seçiniz /option 
 option value="1" ADANA /option
option value="2" ADIYAMAN /option 
option value="3" AFYONKARAHİSAR /option 
….
option value="78" KARABÜK /option
option value="70" selected="" KARAMAN /option 
option value="36" KARS /option 
option value="37" KASTAMONU /option
….